# Hibernate one to many using something other than a primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, persistence, one-to-many

I have a class `A` that has a set of `B`'s. However, these two objects are linked by fields that are NOT the primary key.

For `B`, I can use `<key column>`, but how do I specify that the join should be in `A`.`secondary_column`? Not `A`.`table_primary_key_id` ?

```
<class table="a">
    <id column="table_primary_key_id">
    </id>
    <property column="secondary_column" />

    <set table="B" lazy="false" >
        <key column="B_not_primary" />
        <one-to-many class="BClass" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Comment: I don't think Hibernate will let you do what you want.

Comment: Hibernate really SHOULDN'T let you do this. This reeks of bad database design. What issue are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm trying to solve bad database design...it's a 10+ years legacy database :) I hate it, it haunts me. Hopefully i will convince managemnt to change it to something more OO friendly.

Answer (score 4):

Solved with

```
<set name="someSet" table="B" lazy="false">
    <key column="B_not_primary" property-ref="secondary_column" />
    <one-to-many class="BClass" />
</set>
```